# Using Microsoft Access Database to put values in an Excel Template

Tags: excel, templates, ms-access, import, export

I am trying to build a better structure for creating product specifications for our products, Currently everything is done in excel, as a result every time a value is changed, it takes numerous man hours to make that change to all the specifications. Additionally, our inventory of products continues to grow. I am trying to introduce a new system for developing specifications that will allow me to manage the snowball effect of growing specs and increasing work for simple changes to the entire product line.

My question is, if I build a database with all the necessary values for the template we already use (an excel sheet), is there a way I can enter a part number in the excel template and have all the other values populate into the template at their appropriate locations?

I have posted images of the template and a sample of what the Access database could look like.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Data exchange between Access and Excel is possible. The only limitation is how good you are with VBA (and possibly SQL). Beyond that you would be much better off reversing your process and using an Access form instead of an Excel sheet (which can then export to an excel sheet if necessary).

Comment: Thank you, I found another post on using the form design feature. I am currently recreating the template as a form, and utilizing the table fields as the values.